# Is 1 liter always equal to 1 cubic decimeter, independently of temperature, pressure, etc?

Tags: thermodynamics, unit-conversion, volume, metrology

I recently found [this conversion table](http://www.endmemo.com/sconvert/mmol_m3mmol_l.php) for the unit conversion $\rm mmol/m^3 \ \leftrightarrow\ \rm mmol/L$ (millimoles per cubic meter to millimoles per liter)

My physics is very rusty, but just to be sure, is it true that a liter of liquid always corresponds to a particular volume? (i.e.: Doesn't change with regards to temperature, pressure, etc?)

Comment: This isn't a homework question - OP is asking a (basic but) perfectly reasonable question about unit conversion.

Comment: Google has a unit converting feature which can take input in cubic meters and give you liters. That should suggest the answer ;)

Comment: @Chair that isn't my question thought is it? I am asking if the conversion always holds (ie: one liter is always a specific amount of volume) regardless of other paramters we change.

Comment: Meta discussion: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11160/44126

Comment: @DarioP The point I wished to make was that if the unit converter can do such things without specifying other parameters, it strongly suggests that the units measure the same physical quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it true that a liter of liquid always corresponds to a particular volume?

Yes, this is correct. The relationship
$$
1\:\mathrm{L} = 10^{-3} \:\mathrm{m}^3
\tag 1
$$
(i.e. one cubic meter is a thousand liters) is universal and it does not depend on anything. The liter is a unit of volume - by definition, it's a cubic decimeter.

To convert between $\rm mmol/L$ and $\rm mmol/m^3$, simply insert the relationship above:
\begin{align}
\rm
1\: mmol/L
& =
\rm 1\:mmol / (10^{-3}\:m^3)
\\ & =
\rm 10^{3}\:mmol / m^3,
\end{align}
and vice versa.